# What is the relation between Virtual Machine Manager and KVM/QEMU?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

1. What is the relation between [Virtual Machine Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Machine_Manager) and
   KVM/QEMU?  The  Wikipedia links says

   > In computing, the Red Hat Virtual Machine Manager, also known as virt-manager, is a desktop **virtual machine manager**

   and links "virtual machine manager" to
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor. So if Virtual Machine
   Manager is a hypervisor, then what is KVM/QEMU?
2. Why is VirtualBox not separated into two things in parallel to
   Virtual Machine Manager and KVM/QEMU? In VirtualBox, which part is
   similar to Virtual Machine Manager, and which part similar to
   KVM/QEMU? Or is VirtualBox itself more similar to Virtual Machine Manager or to KVM/QEMU?
3. Is it correct that libvirt is a server process, and VMM a client process? Is QEMU also a server to VMM? What is the relation and difference between QEMU and libvirt processes? Do all the four components communicate by KVM <->QEMU <-> libvirt <-> VMM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I’m not sure why the Wikipedia article links that particular phrase to the hypervisor article; the description of Virtual Machine Manager [on its own web site](https://virt-manager.org/) is more accurate:

   > The **virt-manager** application is a desktop user interface for managing virtual machines through libvirt.

   VMM isn’t a hypervisor itself, it’s a GUI used to manage virtual machines (and LXC containers). VMM and the VMs it manages run in separate processes; in QEMU’s case, VMM and QEMU communicate using Unix domain sockets (under `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu`).
2. VirtualBox is split into [multiple components](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#technical-components). The GUI you’re presumably used to is one component; VMs can be run separately and managed using other tools, *e.g.* [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage). The GUI is similar to Virtual Machine Manager, and the VM engine is similar to KVM/QEMU. They also run in separate processes.
3. As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502895/86440), `libvirtd` is a dæmon, which might qualify as a server process in your terminology. VMM is a libvirt client. VMM doesn’t communicate directly with QEMU, so it’s not a QEMU client. QEMU runs a virtual machine (*i.e.* it emulates the underlying hardware and handles communications with the host), `libvirtd` manages virtual machines (*i.e.* it manages images, storage, starting and stopping VMs, etc.). KVM provides hardware acceleration on systems which provide hypervisor support in hardware; when run with KVM, QEMU doesn’t need to handle non-virtualisable CPU instructions, the hardware takes care of them.

   Communications between the four components you mention are as follows:

   - QEMU uses KVM *via* its `/dev/kvm` device node;
   - libvirt connects to QEMU using domain sockets, as described above;
   - VMM connects to libvirt also using domain sockets, as far as I can tell.

   The whole libvirt setup is loosely coupled: VMs continue running even if VMM and/or `libvirtd` are stopped, and `libvirtd` can reconnect to VMs it manages (if it has an XML descriptor for the VMs).

Comment: Thanks. Can the VM engines of VirtualBox and KVM/QEMU also communicate with their GUI by internet domain sockets? If yes, does that mean a GUI can connect to a nonlocal VM engine of VirtualBox or KVM/QUMU, by internet domain sockets?

Comment: I don’t know about VirtualBox, but VMM can connect to remote systems, using SSH.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What does KVM do about virtual machines? (implement?) (2)"QEMU runs a virtual machine, libvirtd manages virtual machines". Isn't running virtual machines part of managing virtual machines? What differences are between the purposes of QEMU and libvirtd? (3) When QEMU works without KVM, does QEMU do the job of KVM?  When QEMU works with KVM, does QEMU do less job?

Comment: (4) In virtualbox, where "VMs can be run separately and managed using other tools, e.g. VBoxManage". In KVM/QEMU case, QEMU runs VMs, libvirt manages VMs, and VMM does what? What does VBoxManage correspond to, VMM or QEMU or both? Is there something similar to QEMU in virtualBox?

Comment: (1-3) See the updated answer. (4) Point 1 in the answer explains what VMM does. VBoxManage corresponds to `virsh`. I’m not sure what you’re looking for in VirtualBox, I gave the link to the list of components, you should be able to find what you need there.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is it correct that QEMU is the engine, while KVM is an add on and doesn't perform emulation? (2) "QEMU runs a virtual machine (i.e. it emulates the underlying hardware and handles communications with the host)," by "run", do you mean  "emulate" or  "start" which is done  by libvirt as you wrote? (3) Is the relation between QEMU and libvirtd server-client?

Comment: (1) No. (2) That’s answered by what I wrote between parentheses. (3) No.

Comment: Let me try the last time.   (3) What is the relation between QEMU and libvirtd, if not server-client? "libvirt connects to QEMU using domain sockets, as described here" looks server-client to me, though the link under "here" refers back to your own reply.

Comment: "your fixation on server-client relationships, your fixation on taxonomies, and your definition of server" are because I don't know other relationships that can be described this one, and the only other relationship that I know different from server-client is peer-to-peer, which doesn't seem to be a better fit.

Comment: (1) Regarding QEMU and KVM, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509474 (3) In which way do you think of the relation between QEMU and libvirt, if I may ask?

Comment: I think a better way to consider the libvirt-QEMU connection is that it’s a command-and-control connection, not a client-server connection. To me, a client-server connection implies that the server’s main purpose is to serve its clients’ requests; this isn’t the case here, since QEMU can function without libvirt and its main purpose is to emulate a system, not serve libvirt’s requests.