# What are the processes started for running a virtual machine under Virtual Machine Manager?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I am trying to figure out what processes are run when I start a KVM virtual machine under Virtual Machine Manager. Are these all the processes started for that purpose? What do they do respectively?

```
$ ps -A | grep -i kvm
11986 ?        00:00:21 kvm-pit/11965

$ ps -A | grep -i qemu
11965 ?        01:30:42 qemu-system-x86

$ ps -A | grep -i virt
 4253 ?        00:00:00 virtlogd
 4296 ?        00:01:19 libvirtd
11866 ?        00:11:01 virt-manager
```

Answer (score 3):

`man` would answer your question for a number of these.

`kvm-pit` is a kernel thread used for [PIT timer interrupt injection](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/api.txt).

`qemu-system-x86` (probably [`qemu-system-x86_64`](https://manpages.debian.org/qemu-system-x86_64)) is the QEMU x86 system emulator.

[`virtlogd`](https://manpages.debian.org/virtlogd) is the VM logging dæmon, used to handle logs from VM consoles.

[`libvirtd`](https://manpages.debian.org/libvirtd) is the libvirt VM management dæmon.

[`virt-manager`](https://manpages.debian.org/virt-manager) is the Virtual Machine Manager GUI.