# Is KVM a hypervisor?

Tags: kvm, qemu, virt-manager, virsh

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification says QEMU is type 2 hypervisor, and KVM can be both type 1 and 2 hypervisor:

> The distinction between these two types is not always clear. For instance, Linux's Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) and FreeBSD's bhyve are kernel modules[6] that effectively convert the host operating system to **a type-1 hyperviso**r.[7] At the same time, **since Linux distributions and FreeBSD are still general-purpose operating systems, with applications competing with each other for VM resources**, KVM and bhyve can also be categorized as type-2 hypervisors.

How is "Linux distributions and FreeBSD are still general-purpose operating systems, with applications competing with each other for VM resources" the  reason for KVM to be a type 2 hypervisor?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine says

> By itself, **KVM does not perform any emulation**. Instead, it exposes the
>   /dev/kvm interface, which a userspace host can then use to:
>
> - Set up the guest VM's address space. The host must also supply a firmware image (usually a custom BIOS when emulating PCs) that the
>     guest can use to bootstrap into its main OS.
> - Feed the guest simulated I/O.
> - Map the guest's video display back onto the system host.
>
> On Linux, QEMU versions 0.10.1 and later is one such userspace host.
>   QEMU uses KVM when available to virtualize guests at near-native
>   speeds, but otherwise falls back to software-only emulation.

If "KVM does not perform any emulation", can KVM be [a hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification)

> A hypervisor or virtual machine monitor (VMM) is computer software, firmware or hardware that creates and runs virtual machines.

?

Can KVM work as a hypervisor without another hypervisor like QEMU?

Can libvirt also work directly with KVM, without QEMU?

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/658511/

Comment: The Type 1/Type 2 distinction dates back to the 1970s, and in particular was created with such computers in mind, and doesn't make as much sense today as a practical distinction.

Answer (score 4):

> How is "Linux distributions and FreeBSD are still general-purpose operating systems, with applications competing with each other for VM resources" the reason for KVM to be a type 2 hypervisor?

The strict interpretation of type 1/type 2 hypervisors is that

- type 1 hypervisors run alone, and any user-level applications run inside a guest operating system managed by the hypervisor;
- type 2 hypervisors run on top of a host operating system, which can continue to be used alongside whatever guests are managed by the hypervisor.

The distinction isn’t so clear-cut in practice. For example, Xen, which is widely thought of as a type 1 hypervisor, still needs the help of a “Dom0” Linux guest to manage the system’s resources; so it’s not entirely autonomous on bare metal.

Likewise, KVM can be considered a type 2 hypervisor because it runs on top of a host operating system, the Linux kernel, and that host operating system can run other processes alongside whatever VMs are managed by KVM.

> If "KVM does not perform any emulation", can KVM be a hypervisor?

Yes, hypervisors don’t imply emulation.

> Can KVM work as a hypervisor without another hypervisor like QEMU?

Yes, see [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/658511/) for an example.

> Can libvirt also work directly with KVM, without QEMU?

No, it only supports [KVM with QEMU](https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html).